# Django form fails to display

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a simple Django form being passed through a view to a template where it should display, but, for a reason that I -- after 5 hours -- have failed to deduce, it does not.  Any and all ideas welcome, I'm dying to solve this irksome problem.

I have the following Django form:

```
class BandAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
    LENGTH_CHOICES = ( ('XS', 'XS'),
                       ('S', 'S'),
                       ('M', 'M') )
    length = forms.Select(choices=LENGTH_CHOICES)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    band_sku = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    # override the default __init__ so we can set the request
    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(BandAddToCartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # custom validation to check for cookies
    def clean(self):
        if self.request:
            if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Cookies must be enabled.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

It is passed to the template through the following view:

```
def show_custom_watches(request,
                        template_name="catalog/custom_watches.html"):
    bands = Band.objects.all()
    page_title = "Custom Watches"
    meta_keywords = "custom, watches, beaded"
    meta_description = "Custom beaded watches for every occassion."
    return render_to_response(template_name, 
                              locals(), 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #add to cart, create bound form
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = BandAddToCartForm(request, postdata)
        #check if posted data is valid
        if form.is_valid():
            #add to cart and redirect to cart page
            cart.add_band_to_cart(request)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        # it's a GET, create the unbound form. Note request as a kwarg
        band_form = BandAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':')

        # set the test cookie on our first GET request
        request.session.set_test_cookie()
        return render_to_response("catalog/custom_watches.html",
                                  locals(), 
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Lastly, here is the relevant bit of template where the form is failing to display:

```
{% for b in bands %}
    <div class="watch_list_item">
        <img class="" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/bands/thumbnails/{{ b.image }}" alt="{{ b.name }}" />
        <div class="watch_form_area">
            <p>{{ b.name }}</p>
            <form method="post" action="." class="cart">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ band_form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="add_product" alt="Add To Cart" class="add_to_cart_button" id="add_only_product" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The Add to cart button appears as it should, but the length selector completely fails to display.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first

```
return render_to_response(template_name, 
                          locals(), 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

always happens before you initialise the form, remove it and it should work.